# Text added to image in GIMP is too low resolution

Tags: gimp, text

I am very new to GIMP and am having trouble with a project. I am trying to add text to an image to create cover art for an album. I have added the image, which is 1000x1000 pixels, and then added some text layers over it. For some reason, when the text is at a proper size, it is really low resolution and pixelated. It does not look sharp and clear like text should.

Here is the current image with the blurry text: [image: Image with Blurry Text]

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Feel free to let me know if there's any other information I can provide. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For a start, make sure that "Antialiasing" is checked in the tool options.

[image]